# Pushing and Pulling an nested array with setState with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im doing an application where I have one state with some results of athletes.

This is how my data is organized:

```
const startData = [
  { name: "Medina", results: [5, 5, 17, 17, 5, 1, 2, 1, 9, 9] },
  { name: "Filipe", results: [9, 2, 5, 17, 1, 3, 9, 2, 17, 1] },
  { name: "Jordy", results: [3, 3, 17, 5, 2, 9, 3, 5, 9, 1] },
  { name: "Italo", results: [1, 5, 17, 5, 17, 2, 17, 9, 2, 1] },
  { name: "Kolohe", results: [2, 17, 5, 2, 3, 3, 17, 17, 5, 1] },
  { name: "Kanoa", results: [9, 9, 1, 9, 5, 5, 17, 9, 17, 1] }
  //"Italo": []
];
```

Now, I want to add some positions on this results array inside the state. For instance:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: startData };
  }

handleChange = surfer => event => {
    this.setState("HOW TO ADD THIS EVENT VALUE INSIDE A SURFER RESULTS")
};
```

So, for instance, for the surfer with name "Medina" I want to add an element inside this results array (the value of the event.target.value)

How can I do this?

Comment: It would make more sense to pass to `handleChange` an index of the object you want to change instead of surfer name.

Comment: I was thinking about this too Marzelin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access and modify your state like this

```
handleChange = surfer => event => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        data : prev.data.map(item =>{
            if(item.name === surfer.name)
                return {...item, results: item.results.concat(event.target.value)}

            return item
        })
    }))
};
```

`map` over your data checking if `surfer` is the selected one, case true `spread` the original object, and `concat` to it's `results` the `e.target.value`. Case false just return the `item`.

To remove an element use `filter`

```
handleChange = surfer => event => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        data : prev.data.map(item =>{
            if(item.name === surfer.name)
                return {...item, results: item.results.filter(i => 1 === 1)}

            return item
        })
    }))
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im getting an error: 
TypeError: prev.map is not a function

Comment: Thanks again @Dupocas. I didnt understand what array are you talking about, sorry for that. I tried this.setState(prev =>
     prev[this.state.data].map(item => {
      if (item.surfer === surfer)
    return { ...item, results: item.results.concat(event.target.value) };

But got the same error

Comment: hahaha Can you please update the answer with your `state` object? So that I can make a more specific example

Comment: sure. doing that

Comment: Thanks so much Dupocas. Im just editing a small detail on the if condidition and it worked like a charm

Comment: You're welcome!! Glad to hear. Grande fã de Fortaleza aliás ^^ Abraços